# INSERT values query throws error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle 11g and I get the following error when i enter the following query

```
INSERT INTO Customer(Customer_id, First_Name, Last_Name, DOB, Gender, PAN_No) 
VALUES(301, ‘Robert’, ‘William’, 1986-10-05, ‘M’,’PQ56794’);
```

ERROR:

> ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Comment: replace all the quotes with proper quote characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is

```
’PQ56794’
```

Try the below if it works:

```
INSERT INTO Customer(Customer_id, First_Name, Last_Name, DOB, Gender, PAN_N0) 
VALUES(301, 'Robert', 'William', to_date('19861005','YYYYMMDD'), 'M','PQ56794');
```

Tip : Always copy from Notepad to avoid problems related to quote.

Comment: No i get
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Comment: I have edited my answer to have date inserted. Try that it should work.